# python with open - rename file

Tags: python, bufferedreader

I am using python `with open` to read a file.

```
with open('/Users/ks/Downloads/file name 1.pdf', 'rb') as data:
    print(data)

<_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/ks/Downloads/file name 1.pdf'>
```

I am trying to rename the file to `file_name_1.pdf` before uploading. Is there a way to parse the file name from data and rename? I'd like to replace   with `_`.

Comment: Why not use `os.rename()`?

Comment: `data.name` would have the filename, but I wouldn't recommend renaming the file while it's open.

Comment: move and open, no?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file with this:

```
import os
file_path = '/Users/kevalshah/Downloads/file name 1.pdf'
os.rename(file_path, file_path.replace(' ', '_'))
```

to rename from `data` you need this:

```
import os
file_path = '/Users/kevalshah/Downloads/file name 1.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as data:
    file_path = data.name

# !!! file was closed first
os.rename(file_path, file_path.replace(' ', '_'))
```

Comment: In the edge case where a Folder has a space in it, this method is going to change those spaces as well~

Answer (score 0):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can help make sure you don't mess anything up unexpectedly. There's no reason to open a file just to change its name:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = '/Users/kevalshah/Downloads/file name 1.pdf'

# Convert to Path
file_path = Path(file_path)

# Modify the Name 
# Use .name attribute to ensure you're just modifying the filename
new_name = file_path.name.replace(' ', '_')

# Use .with_name and .rename to modify the filename:
file_path = file_path.rename(file_path.with_name(new_name)))
# Your file has been renamed~
```